# How do I modify the shebang line in a Perl or shell script?

Tags: linux, perl, search, scripting, replace

I have lots of Perl scripts that need to be updated to a consistent version required and have various versions and flags currently. All of these statements lie in the first line of the script. I have not had much luck here, obviously trying to use sed but is there something better?

Example line that needs to be edited

```
 #!/opt/local/bin/perl5
```

I tried a bash script as follows, but it does not work for me.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Changing Perl headers in the following..." 
for file in $(ls $1*.pl)
do
    echo $file
    sed 's/#!\/opt\/local/bin\/perl5/#![PERL5]/' $file > /dev/null
# Perl Version: PERL5
done
```

Any help from someone experienced with sed would be great! Thanks!

Comment: You're not escaping the slash before "bin"?

Answer (score 4):

Use Perl to fix your Perl scripts.  You can use braces for the regexes to avoid [leaning toothpick syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome).

```
perl -i -pe 's{^#!/opt/local/bin/perl5}{#!/some/new/path}' *.pl
```

`-i` and `-p` are used to edit files in place, kinda like sed.  See [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) for details.

Comment: Or you can just use `:` in your `s` command in `sed` to fix leaning toothpicks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what it is you want.  If you're wanting to edit all of the files in `$DIR` so that their first line is `#![PERL5]` instead of `#!/opt/local/bin/perl5`, this will do that:

```
sed --in-place '1s:^#!/opt/local/bin/perl5:#![PERL5]:' "$DIR"/*.pl
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to do. But it did not work. added DIR and escaped !'s                                                             <blink>     sed --in-place '1s:#\!/opt/local/bin/perl5:#\![PERL5]:' "./"/*.pl </blink>

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "added DIR and escaped".  `DIR` is supposed to be the directory that contains your `.pl` files.  This script will change them "in-place", so no new directories should be created at all.

Comment: I mean I defined it :) The bangs(!) are now \!

Comment: Don't escape the exclamation points.  Just put exactly what I have in my sed command.

Answer (score 1):

To edit files with perl, you'd use the `-pi` switches. Since you only wanted to change the first line, I was considering a way to do so without causing the regex to change anything else in the file. This little hack will allow that. Not sure if it's worth the effort, since shebang-like strings should not really be found elsewhere.

```
perl -pi.bak -e '
    $x //= s|^#!/opt/local/bin/perl5|#![PERL5]|; 
    undef $x if eof;' *.pl
```

The `//=` operator will not attempt to execute the RHS if `$x` is already defined, so this will in effect only perform one change. The addition of `undef $x` at `eof` will reset the variable for the next file, causing each file in the argument list to be altered once.

You may not want backups, in which case you'd remove `.bak` from the `-i` switch.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose if you want to change perl5 to perl6
Try this:
perl -pi -e 's/perl5/perl6/' $file